# Error on data type from trainable_variables

Tags: tensorflow-transform

I am running tensorflow-transform and getting error on trainable_variables. Is it fine to get these messages ?

(cmle-env) debasish:transform debasish.das$ python examples/simple_example.py 
2018-03-20 14:36:30.468584: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
ERROR:tensorflow:Cannot identify data type for collection trainable_variables. Skipping.
ERROR:tensorflow:Cannot identify data type for collection trainable_variables. Skipping.
ERROR:tensorflow:Cannot identify data type for collection trainable_variables. Skipping.
ERROR:tensorflow:Cannot identify data type for collection trainable_variables. Skipping.
WARNING:tensorflow:Expected binary or unicode string, got type_url: "type.googleapis.com/tensorflow.AssetFileDef"
value: "\n\t\n\007Const:0\022\033vocab_string_to_int_uniques"

WARNING:tensorflow:Expected binary or unicode string, got type_url: "type.googleapis.com/tensorflow.AssetFileDef"
value: "\n\t\n\007Const:0\022\033vocab_string_to_int_uniques"

ERROR:tensorflow:Cannot identify data type for collection trainable_variables. Skipping.
ERROR:tensorflow:Cannot identify data type for collection trainable_variables. Skipping.
ERROR:tensorflow:Cannot identify data type for collection trainable_variables. Skipping.
ERROR:tensorflow:Cannot identify data type for collection trainable_variables. Skipping.
[{u's_integerized': 0,
  u'x_centered': -1.0,
  u'x_centered_times_y_normalized': -0.0,
  u'y_normalized': 0.0},
 {u's_integerized': 1,
  u'x_centered': 0.0,
  u'x_centered_times_y_normalized': 0.0,
  u'y_normalized': 0.5},
 {u's_integerized': 0,
  u'x_centered': 1.0,
  u'x_centered_times_y_normalized': 1.0,
  u'y_normalized': 1.0}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is not an issue, I believe what you're seeing a bug that was recently fixed in TF.Transform that would cause these errors to get printed incorrectly.

It was fixed here and will be included in the soon to be released TF.Transform 0.6.0.
https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/commit/4b45bfe96b53bde91f97464016fa1f9deb68ca8a#diff-7b3a53e6030c862a8adbe513b2271488R150